# Bypass file_exists[rfi,lfi] in my code, is it possible?

Tags: php

I've got the following piece of code in my web application:

```
$data = "dir/files/".$_GET['f'].".pdf";
```

Couple of lines down I got:

```
if(file_exists($data)){    
include($data);
```

Could an attacker bypass that to exploit an RFI on my system? Or is it LFI only?

Answer (score 1):

Best to whitelist (not blacklist) characters allowed in $_GET['f'].

```
if (preg_match("[^A-Za-z0-9_-]", $_GET['f'])) {
  fail();
} else {
  // your logic here
}
```

Notice that I didn't put "." or "/" in the whitelist. That was intentional.